# How to calculate parallel speedup between two algorithm

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc

suppose I have algorithm 1 and 2, their sequential execution time is ts1 and ts2.  their parallel execution time is tp1 and tp2.

Now when calculating the speed up for both algorithm, which of the following is true?

- min(ts1,ts2)/tp1    for algorithm 1
- min(ts1,ts2)/tp2    for algorithm 2

or

- ts1/tp1  for algorithm 1
- ts2/tp2  for algorithm 2

in other words, for numerator, should I use the best sequential time or their own sequential time?

Answer (score 1):

### Short Version:

None of the above

---

## Fig.1:

```
                                                     a SPEEDUP
                                                       BETWEEN
                                                     a BLACK-BOX <PROCESS_2>
   [START]                                             and
         +-----------------------------------------+ a BLACK-BOX <PROCESS_1>
         |                                         |
      [T0]         [T0+ts1]             [T0+ts1+tp1] 
         |                |                        |   
         |                |                        |   
         v                v                        v
         |________________|R.0: ____.____.____.____| ~~ <PAR.1:1> == [SEQ]
         |                |R.1? ____.____|         :
         |                |R.2? ____|    :         :
         |                |R.3? ____|    :         :
         |                |         :    :         :
         |<SEQ.1>>>>>>>>>>|         :    :         :
         |                |<PAR.1:N>:    :         :
                          |         :    :         :
                                    :    :         :
                                    :    :         [FINISH] using 1 PAR-RESOURCE
                                    :    [FINISH]        if using 2 PAR-RESOURCEs
                                    [FINISH]             if using 4 PAR-RESOURCEs
```

<sub>( Execution time flows from left to right, from `[T0]` .. to `[T0 + ts1 + tp1]`. The sketched order of `[SEQ]`, `[PAR]` sections was chosen just for illustrative purpose here, can be opposite, as process-flow sections' durations ordering is commutative in principle )</sub>

---

### A TL;DR; Version:

a bit formal simplification of the **`[SEQ]+[PAR]`** process-flows above may help to both answer and also understand why.

Needless to tell any HPC planners, that **Amdahl Law rules** ( [the better if **extended form** of Amdahl, the **overhead + atomicity aware** formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) were used ).

We see, the more resources **`R.i`** were used in `[PAR]`-section of the `PROCESS_1`, the shorter the **`tp1`** may get. Here is the power of `[PAR]`-processing.

Given just the pair of tuples `( ts1, tp1 )` and `( ts2, tp2 )`, no one can assume any potential Amdahl Law -- resources-driven ( as demonstrated in Fig.1 ) -- speedup, but if one strives to just compare the two postulated  implementations, having potentially different internal processing, the possible speedup **`S`** can be formulated as:

```
      max( [ ts1 + tp1 ], [ ts2, tp2 ] )
S =  ______________________________________
      min( [ ts1 + tp1 ], [ ts2, tp2 ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental issue with your question. That is why you are stuck. The issue is that *Speedup* is defined for processors, not algorithms.

> *In computer architecture, speedup is a process for increasing the performance between two systems processing the same problem. More technically, it is the improvement in speed of execution of a task executed on two similar architectures with different resources.*

<sup>Definition taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup).</sup>

Comment: @user3666197 - Please don't make baseless accusations against someone and persecute them with constant rollbacks. Using a quotation that is shortened by a whole three words does not justify your aggression towards this person.